# Play audio when javascript alert pops up and stop playing when the alert closes

Tags: javascript, html, audio, frontend, web-frontend

I'm trying to play an audio when a javascript alert pops up and stop playing the audio when the user closes the alert. But  the audio is not stopping when the user closes the alert.And the alert keeps appearing again and again even after I close it.

```
const audio = new Audio("sounds/Sparkle - Your Name.mp3");
audio.play();
audio.loop = false;
if(!alert("Time for some anime")){
           audio.pause();
}
```

Comment: FYI, this isn't going to work on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `confirm()` instead of `alert()`

```
const audio = new Audio("sounds/Sparkle - Your Name.mp3");
audio.play();
audio.loop = false;

function after() {
    audio.pause();
}

if(confirm("Time for some anime"))
    after();
else
    after();
```

or shorter with `confirm("continue to pause") ? after() : after();`

you can test it here :

https://jsfiddle.net/82wsqhuL/2/